# Find minimum, maximum and average of random number in java

Tags: java, arrays, max, average, minimum

I need to randomize 1000 numbers, and I want to find the average of all the numbers, the smallest and the largest number, but I can't output it. Here is my code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 
        int sum = 0;
        int min;
        int max;
        double average;
        int number = 0;
        int[] A = new int[1000]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            A[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
            System.out.print(A[i] + " ");
            if (((i + 1) % 10) == 0) {
                System.out.println();
            }
            sum = sum + A[i];
            average = sum / A.length;

            min = A[0];
            if (A[i] < min) {
                min = A[i];
            }
            max = A[0];
            if (A[i] > max) {
                max = A[i];
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The average value is:" + average);
        System.out.println("The minimum value is:" + min);
        System.out.println("The maximum value is:" + max);
    }
}
```

I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You need to initialize min, max ,average for example: int min = 0; btw you should create at least 2 for loops first for initialize array and second for calculations

Comment: By the way: `ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints( 0 , 99 ).limit( 1_000 ).summaryStatistics()` as seen on [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/XSvowh): `IntSummaryStatistics{count=1000, sum=48008, min=0, average=48.008000, max=98}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you initilize your variables that you print with the results (min,max,average) the program has to work, but you have some mistakes in the code, if you change that, everything must to be ok :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in); 
  int sum=0;
  int min=0;
  int max=0;
  double average=0;
  int[] A = new int[1000]; 
  for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++)
  {
     A[i]=(int)(Math.random()*100);
     }
     min=A[0];
     max=A[0];
     for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++){
    System.out.print(A[i]+" ");
    if(((i+1) % 10) == 0){
        System.out.println();
     }
     sum=sum+A[i];  
     if (A[i]<min){
        min=A[i];
     }
     if (A[i]>max){
        max=A[i];
     }
  }
  average = sum / A.length;
  
  System.out.println("The average value is:"+ average);
  System.out.println("The minimum value is:"+ min);
  System.out.println("The maximum value is:"+ max);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array1 {

public static void main(String[] args)
{ 
  Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in); 
  int sum=0;
  int min = 0;
  int max = 0;
  double average = 0;
  int number=0;
  int[] A = new int[1000];
  for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++)
  {
      A[i]=(int)(Math.random()*100); // generates 1000 rand ints initially
  }
  min=A[0];
  max=A[0];
  for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++)
  {
     System.out.print(A[i]+" ");
     if(((i+1) % 10) == 0){
        System.out.println();
     }
     sum=sum+A[i];  
     
     if (A[i]<min){
        min=A[i];
     }
     
     if (A[i]>max){
        max=A[i];
     }
  }
  average = sum / A.length;
  
 
  System.out.println("The average value is:"+ average);
  System.out.println("The minimum value is:"+ min);
  System.out.println("The maximum value is:"+ max);


  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to look and checkout it should explain your current problem which is your Class Array is Public and you need to declare it.

-> https://learn.sourcegraph.com/how-to-troubleshoot-java-error-class-is-public-should-be-declared-in-its-own-file

Answer (score 0):

This isn't actually fixing your code but if you're using Java 8+ the following would be more elegant:

```java
public class Statistics {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // implement user input if that's a requirement
    IntStream input = new Random().ints(1000, 0, 1000000);

    // statistics
    IntSummaryStatistics statistics = input.summaryStatistics();

    // avg, min, max
    System.out.println(statistics.getAverage());
    System.out.println(statistics.getMin());
    System.out.println(statistics.getMax());
  }

}
```